# python: import random for multiple question

Tags: python, random, import, user-input

I have already created a `login()`. Trying to ask a random question each time and if answered correctly to run `login()`.

Below is the outline of what I am trying to do:

```
>>> def human_check():
question1 == raw_input('1+1=')#question.1#
while question1 !== '2':
    print 'sorry robot , try again'
else:
    return login()
question2 == raw_input('the cow jumped over the ....')#question.2#
while question2 !== '2':
    print 'sorry robot , try again'
else:
    return login()
import random
random.question
```

I imported the `random` module but how do I group the questions so that `random.` will work?

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Comment: thank you for that . i completely thought it would work idk why

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
import random

questions = []
questions.append(("1+1=", "2"))
questions.append(("the cow jumped over the ....", "moon"))

def human_check():
    random_question = random.choice(questions)
    question, answer = random_question
    user_answer = raw_input(question)
    if user_answer != answer:
       print "Sorry, try again."
    else:
       return login()
```

Basically, if you maintain some list of questions, you can use `random.choice` to make a random selection from that list.